# JTable dynamic listener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, jcombobox

Things that i am trying to achieve:

1. Select the row and add in values, the first value at `col=0` will determine what will generate at `col=2` and what `col=2` value is will generate values for `col=3`.
2. To achieve what i have said on the selected row, for example if i have more than 2 rows of data which is empty. When i fill in the first row of data, the second row of data should be remain untouched. The second row of values are only generated when i click of the second row value.
3. Lastly this is just another button that i have which is a "save" button where it will retrieve the data from the table and store it. However i am getting this problem where when my mouse is still selected on the cell, that selected cell value is not being passed in and stored. So is there a way when i click the button, i can deselect the cell?. Side note i have used `clearSelection` and it does not work.

Currently what i have:

1. At the moment i managed to do the change where when i click a value from the `col=0` and it will update the value for `col=1`. However i am now stuck at how i am going to get the value from the `col=1` to generate my values for `col=3` which is the last col. I have tried adding another if else in the method however that does not work.
2. At the moment the values i add in are `combobox` these combobox values are derived from a method that passes in the selection choice of the values from their respective cols.

Method for table listener:

```
 public static void TableListen(JTable Model,SQLObject so){
        Model.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) {
                if(Model.getModel().getRowCount()!=0){
                    if(Model.getSelectedColumn()==0){
                        if(!Model.getModel().getValueAt( Model.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString().equals("-Selection-")){
                            String treatmentChoice=Model.getModel().getValueAt(Model.getSelectedRow(), Model.getSelectedColumn()).toString();
                            JComboBox<String> comboBox = null;
                            TableColumn feedingCol=Model.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
                            comboBox=DosageObject.GetListOfMedication(so,treatmentChoice);
                            feedingCol.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Calling a `JTable` variable `Model` is extremely confusing, as a `JTable` represent a view on a `TableModel`.

Comment: Can you edit your question so that it is clearer what it is that you are asking?